# C# copy function richtextbox with formatting

Tags: c#, select, formatting, copy, richtextbox

How do I make a button that allows me to copy like the ctrl+c function.
I want to select a part of a rich text box and when the button is clicked it copies the selected part. With formatting!

Comment: Search web for selecting text in richtextbox ... it's not hard to search.

Comment: Show us what have you tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On button click event you should do something like:

```
if (richTextBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
// Copy the selected text to the Clipboard
Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.SelectedText, TextDataFormat.Text);
```

Comment: What you made works perfectly fine, the one thing i miss it that it loses the formatting. do you happen to know how that works?

Comment: I would suggest you to change TextDataFormat from Text to Rtf